# C# - Skip to an ID in Database

Tags: c#, database

I am about to give up. Tried lots of stuff for 5 hours straight. Nothing is coming to me.

I have a C# application that can add records, delete records from a database. It can also show items in textboxes and I can navigate the items using a next and previous button. Such as below for the Next button,

```
    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (inc != MaxRows - 1)
        {
            inc++;
            NavigateRecords();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have reached the end of available items", "End of Available Items", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

MaxRows is this

```
MaxRows = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows.Count;
```

The method I called above is NavigateRecords and this code is here

```
private void NavigateRecords()
    {
        DataRow dRow = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc];

        txtMaker.Text = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc].ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
        txtModel.Text = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc].ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
        txtPrice.Text = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc].ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
        txtBids.Text = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc].ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString();
        txtScreen.Text = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc].ItemArray.GetValue(5).ToString();
        txtCPU.Text = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc].ItemArray.GetValue(6).ToString();
        txtMemory.Text = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc].ItemArray.GetValue(7).ToString();
        txtHD.Text = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc].ItemArray.GetValue(8).ToString();
        picLaptops.Image = Image.FromFile(ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc].ItemArray.GetValue(9).ToString());
    }
```

I have an AutoNumber ID field in my Access database that the user should be able to skip to (by entering the ID into a textbox) and show the appropriate record in different textboxes (refer to NavigateRecords)

My problem is, how do I even do this? I need the correct row to be displayed in the textboxes from NavigateRecords that will also update the "inc" variable that is set globally to 0. eg, if the user starts up the program and skips to say id 7, it will display that record but when it does this the inc should also update with the row number so that if I clicked next it will take me to id 8 and not id 2... if that makes sense. I have this so far.

```
private void btnSkip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchFor = txtSkip.Text;
        DataRow[] Skip;
        int results = 0;

        Skip = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Select("ID='" + searchFor + "'");

        results = Skip.Length;

        if (results > 0)
        {
            DataRow dr1;

            for (int i = 0; i < MaxRows; i++)
            {
                // who knows what to do here.... or getting every row is even the right thing to do...

            }

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No item found");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If id is unique, then you know that the Select method will only ever return one row. This problem is quite easy with SQL, you can simply SELECT TOP 1 FROM Laptops WHERE id > @currentID ORDER BY id ASC for next, and SELECT TOP 1 FROM Laptops WHERE id < currentID ORDER BY id DESC for previous. In your example above, if id is indeed unique, simply order the table by id, store the current index of the record you are on, and move up or down as long as index > 0 and index < Rows.Count. If id is unique, I can give you an example.

Comment: Also note that if you are using Windows Forms you can use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wcswths(v=vs.80).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158105(v=VS.80).aspx which are Framework controls designed to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modifying your second code sample:

```
private void btnSkip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchFor = txtSkip.Text;
    DataRow[] target = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Select("ID='" + searchFor + "'");
    // I suspect that this should really not be a string, so ("ID=" + searchFor);

    if (target.Count() == 1) {
        inc = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows.IndexOf(target[0]);
        NavigateRecords();
    } else { //there can be no more than one row, so this means no matches
        MessageBox.Show("No item found");
    }
}
```

...this is assuming that ID is a unique identifier within the table.

Comment: Yes, ID is always unique. I pasted in your code but it says "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'" around the if statement (target.Count stuff)

Comment: at IndexOf in your code it says 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'IndexOf' and no extension method 'IndexOf' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: argh, this is what I get for answering without a C# compiler handy. Fix #2: `Rows.IndexOf`

Comment: Kick ass. It works perfectly. I would never have figured that out on my own. You sir are a god.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through your code a bit, seems to me like maybe you should be calling NavigateRecords() within your for loop.

Also, if your just getting into UI development you may want to take look at the MVVM design pattern especially if your working with WPF. If your working with WinForms or something else then perhaps the MVP pattern may be worth looking at. Either way these patterns help to separate the presentation from the application logic and may simplify issues like this.